# How to get user input in PowerShellInstance

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I have a c# WFP program that has a button then when clicked executes a PowershellInstance.

I need to get user input somehow that I can pass into the powershell code block of that button.

*For example: I need to get an IP address and a username.*

I have not found a way to do this yet. Any user prompt from with in the `PowerShellInstace.AddScript` block is ignored. It could be as simple as adding a textbox and somehow passing that into the script block but I not seeing how.

I am using the following code as an example.

```
private void getorgs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"$baseUrl = ""http://$IP:9003/api/v1/admin""
    }
}
```